# Auto display date into field 3 days after selected date

Tags: javascript

I have two date fields. One field has an ID of "dateA" and the other has an ID of "dateB"

What I am looking to do is arrange for the field "dateB" to auto populate the date 3 days after the date selected in field "dateA"

I have this calculation script here:

```
dates.today().withAddedWeeks(form.getCurrentScore("nextReviewPeriod"))
```

but this calculate weeks based on a radio button selection rather that a date calendar entry.

Comment: Add more code to your question! Time is hard. Use moment.js or something.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure what `dates` is... But if your dateA is represeted as a js Date object, you could set dateB to be `new Date(dateA.getTime() + 86400000 * 3)` where `3` is the number of days after dateA. There's probably an even simpler way than that, all without using an extra library.

Comment: Thanks, for the script, I will need the script to link to the field ID so Date A, i.e. 02/10/2019 (ID: "DateA") is a date entry calender field where the user will enter a date, from that date entry, Date B i.e. 05/10/2019 (ID: "DateB") will auto populate a date 3 days from the date selected in Date A.

Answer (score 0):

I always find it simple to work work the unix time. Convert your `dateA` to milliseconds using `new Date(dateA).getTime()` and add `259200000` which is an equivalent of 3 days in milliseconds. i.e `dateBinMilliseconds = new Date(dateA).getTime() + 259200000`. You can then get the date string for `dateB` by `new Date(dateBinMilliseconds).toString()`